# How to get the end node of a tree in python?

Tags: python, node-editor

From a given node tree, what is the most reliable way to get the end node being used for output, if any?

My current approach is to check for the correct output type for the tree (`OUTPUT_MATERIAL`, `OUTPUT_WORLD`...) and for `is_active_output`:

```
nodes = node_tree.nodes

for n in nodes:
    if n.type == 'OUTPUT_WORLD' and n.is_active_output:
        return n

return None
```

However, I see no guarantee that there is only one node with `is_active_output` (I can set this to True in multiple nodes).

The ShaderNodeTree has an `active_input` field, but the value is -1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have experimented with it and this is what i come up with :

- The `active_output` is not a `node` type so it will not contain the active output node, it is `NodeSocketInterface` ( i don't know what this is )
- as you have found you can set multiple nodes `is_active_output` to true and this will be misleading, but apparently this is handled automatically by blender like this : the last selected output node (in the UI ) is set to be the active output and all other output nodes get their `is_active_output` property cleared.
- if you set `is_active_output` to True for multiple nodes the first one in the `node_tree.nodes` list is the active one.
- if you clear the `is_active_output` of all nodes then the first output node in the list `node_tree.nodes` is the active one.

to handle this in code i have two functions to get/set the active output :

```
def set_active(my_node):
        nodes = my_node.id_data.nodes
        for node in nodes :
            if node.type == 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL' :
                node.is_active_output = False
        my_node.is_active_output = True


def get_active(nodes):   
        for node in nodes :
            if node.type == 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL' and node.is_active_output :
                    return node
        for node in nodes :
            if node.type == 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL' :
                    return node
```

Comment: thank you for taking the trouble of experimenting and providing a very complete answer

Comment: you are welcome , I got curious and couldn't stop : )